# escaping variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have script below i am using get value of one parameter

```
var=`ssh -X -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $phost "
cd ; . ./.bash_profile;cd $ORACLE_HOME/dbs; sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOF
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set tab off
set feedback off
select value from v$parameter where name='control_files';
EOF
"`
```

this script this fetching value from table v$parameter and assigning it to variable `var`, now how can i escape $ from v$parameter

i have tried v\$parameter but it didnt help

Comment: you've probably got at least two parse levels occuring there, so try `v\\$parameter`

Comment: @ Marc B i tried that too, it didnt help

Comment: How about `table='v$parameter'` and `select value from ${table} where ...`

Comment: @WalterA  select value from v where name='control_files' primary standby ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @Nomad, you may try (echo 'select ... from v$parameter' | sqlplus /s / as sysdba) or try to parse control_files from the initfile/spfile if this file is on OS and not on ASM  or make "show parameter control_files" and parse the output

Comment: What about \044 (octal representation of $) in place of $?

Comment: First create a script for your sql, scp that script to the target and call that script.

Answer (score 0):

You can cat the code lines into a file during the script run and then run the created script.

Something like:

```
echo "set heading off" > tempfile.sh
echo "set pagesize 0" >> tempfile.sh
echo "set tab off" >> tempfile.sh
echo "set feedback off" >> tempfile.sh 
echo "select value from v${parameter} where name='control_files';" >> tempfile.sh
chmod +x tempfile.sh
./tempfile.sh
```